# hosting an iqy file on a sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export, query

I want to export a list from sharepoint into excel. I can do this export easy with an iqy file. Once I have this iqy file (which by default is saved in my temporary area but I will save it to my desktop) I then link it into excel.

Now i have this list, I want to do a few modifications and then send it to some people, this is where the problem starts.
If i send this file as it is, the link will break as the link is on my computer. So I want to host this IQY file somewhere accessible to the people I want to send it to.
The people I want to send it to do not have access to one specific area other than the sharepoint. I want to host the file on the sharepoint and link it up to the Excel table but when I do this, it appears as though excel downloads a personal copy and links it to my excel again re-creating the original problem.

Is there any way in which I can host the IQY file on sharepoint and link to it?
Or connecting to a sharepoint list WITHOUT using the iqy file?

Thanks in advanced!
Sharepoint Version: 2007
Microsoft Office: 2010

Answer (score 0):

Once you open the IQY file in Excel it will create a connection to the SP site. Then you can save the Excel file and the connection will remain. You can even edit the connection settings to do things like auto-refresh every time the Excel file is opened.

Comment: yes, but if I share that file with someone else and they try to update the excel file with the link, they wont be able to because the link is pointing to the iqy temporary file on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you are doing this.. If you export data from SharePoint List to Excel and after this edit them with active data connection(iqy file or data connection in Excel) data will be changed on SharePoint too, so you have not to sent this Excel to others people, just send them link to SharePoint List where they can open it in Excel too.

The Excel file is only instrument for editing the source data on SharePoint list, so always send links to the main source - the SharePoint List.

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to have a two way connection between iqy and sharepoint list, I am searching this but it seems it is only one-way connection0SP list->iqy), if it is, could you please advise how?